# In jQuery jqXhr, how can I access original xhr.getResponseHeader method?

Tags: jquery

I have been beaten by this [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10338) and I would like to work-around it by accessing `getResponseHeader` method of original xhr object and not the one provided in jqXhr which seems to use (broken) `getAllResponseHeaders`. Is there a way to access it? Without patching jQuery code itself?

Before upgrade to jQuery 1.7 I was using 1.4.2 and it worked. So I am assuming that using xhr's `getResponseHeader` directly will work.

Comment: jqXhr has got `getResponseHeader` too.